# System date format causing date in file to change when copied using IO.File.Copy()

Tags: windows, vb.net

A user ran into an exception the other day when my code tried to parse a date from a line of text in a configuration file. The customer was using the Chinese date localization, so I figured that the issue was the parsing.

However, when reproducing the problem, I found the text in the file itself was in the Chinese format. This file is copied from a backup location, which I verified to **not** be in the Chinese format.

It turns out when the file was previously copied from that location by a call to IO.File.Copy(), the text changed from:

```
22/JUN/2016,00:00:00
```

to

```
22/6月/2016,00:00:00
```

The size of the file even changed.

Due to this, an exception was thrown  when trying to parse that text on this call:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, datetimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The data doesn't have to be localized, so we always use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. However, if the file changes the date format, this breaks.

When I copy and paste the file as usual, the file **doesn't** change, which is even more curious.

I verified this problem to occur on Windows 10, after changing the Regional Format to Chinese (Simplified, China).

Any ideas as to why IO.File.Copy() causes this change?

Comment: `Copy` should not change the file at all.  How are you viewing the file?  It sounds like an encoding issue.  What happens if you compare the bytes in the file using a hex editor?

Comment: Putting "6月" into google translate yields "June".  Is it possible that the original file has an NTFS alternate data stream that is being copied?  Try opening a command prompt in the source directory and exectute "Dir filename /R" to list any alternate streams on filename.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to use "TryParseExact" for parsing the datetime.

Answering your question, there might be few  things you need to look into:

1. Look in to the code used to Copy the file.
2. Try using StreamReader/StreamWriter for copying the file, do specify the Encoding Type.